# EF Code First Lazy Loading null child objects

Tags: null, ef-code-first, lazy-loading

Good afternoon,

I'm having a problem with lazy loading null child objects. Consider the following code:

```
// Retrieve all repairs
var repairs = this.db.Repairs.Include("Brand").Include("Model");

// JUST FOR TESTING PURPOSES
// Some repairs do not have a brand or model. This query returns about 14 results
var reps = this.db.Repairs.Where(r => r.ModelId == 0 || r.BrandId == 0);

// Map the repairs to the viewmodel
var ret = repairs.Select(qRepair => new RepairListViewModel
{
    Brand = qRepair.Brand == null ? "Unkown" : qRepair.Brand.Name,
    CompanyName = qRepair.User.CompanyName,
    CustomerName = qRepair.CustomerName,
    Created = qRepair.Created,
    DamageNumber = qRepair.DamageNumber,
    Id = qRepair.Id,
    Model = qRepair.Model == null ? "Unkown" : qRepair.Model.Name,
    OrderNumber = qRepair.Order.OrderNumber,
    Printed = qRepair.Printed,
    Status = qRepair.Status
});
```

After this the list is returned for usage in a Kendo UI Grid.

However, there are no repairs in it with Brand or Model name "Unkown". It seems to skip the repairs where the Brand or Model is null. What am I missing here?!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not you just do the following Select(x=>x.ModelId==0 ||...) and than ToList() in the new List you have the repair objects just foreach and create your view models.

Comment: @BassamAlugili that indeed is a solid workaround. However, I'm trying to figure out why the above is acting like it is.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this syntax for the problem:

```
var query = from pro in db.Repais
      select new {
                   Brand = qRepair.Brand == null ? "Unkown" : qRepair.Brand.Name,
                   CompanyName = qRepair.User.CompanyName,
                   CustomerName = qRepair.CustomerName,
                   Created = qRepair.Created,
                   DamageNumber = qRepair.DamageNumber,
                   Id = qRepair.Id,
                   Model = qRepair.Model == null ? "Unkown" : qRepair.Model.Name,
                   OrderNumber = qRepair.Order.OrderNumber,
                   Printed = qRepair.Printed,
                   Status = qRepair.Status
                  };

return query.ToList<Object>();
```

I can not say what the problem exactly in your code. You can try to load the Linq dll in VS and try to debug to find some error info. do not forget the include. But I think the problem because of the reutrn type in the datacontext.

I hope this will help u.